# Test doubles in Jasmine

Tags: javascript, jasmine

Can anyone help me with creating and using test doubles in Jasmine?  I have  mostly used Ruby before and if I was testing a Class method within RSpec that received instances of another class as a parameter I'd use a double.

I can't seem to find a clear explanation on how you would use the equivalent of a double in Jasmine for Javascript functions?

Example:

If I was testing a class called Game in Ruby and wanted to bring in an instance of Player I would have created a double something like:
player1 = double 'Player1', lost?: true

Is this possible in Jasmine?

Comment: how about using spyOn to mock methods or createSpy to create mock objects?

Answer (score 0):

Jasmine has an API to allow creation of [Spies](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies:_%3Ccode%3EcreateSpyObj%3C/code%3E), these are the same as Mocks or Test doubles.

```
var player = jasmine.createSpyObj('player', ['lost']);
player.lost.and.callFake(function() {
  return true;
});
```

alternatively, JS is not strongly typed so you can just create a vanilla object:

```
var player = {
    lost : function(){
        return true;
    }
};
```